# C# ASP.net render HTML String

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, rendering

I have a bit of code in my markup like this :

```
<% Response.Write(((String)objRow["Post"]).Trim()); %>
```

The value in objRow["Post"] is HTML markup - similar to this:

```
<p><span style="color: #ff0000;">asdsada</span></p>
```

The content of which was created using tinymce. I now want to render the resultant html - basically a view function of a previously created save function.

At the moment, my markup literally spits out the HTML you see there onto my website - but what I really want is a red line of text saying asdsada.

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it sounds like the value you are trying to display is already html encoded. try this:

```
<%= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string)objRow["Post"]) %>
```

Comment: This throws the following error:  CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: add the cast to string

Answer (score 6):

My version of Asp.net is little bit higher, but this might help someone, who uses .net Core 2.0 MVC.

I am using the following approach for rendering html in my ***Asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC*** project (the html is created via *Tiny MCE* and saved in the database, after that it is rendered on the Razor View).

**Please, try these two steps**:

1) include *System.Net* in *_ViewImports.cshtml*:

```
@using System.Net
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

2) render the html using *HtmlDecode* in your *View.cshtml*:

```
@Html.Raw(@WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.MyHtmlData))
```

**This works for me**, hope it helps!

But without *HtmlDecode*, *Html.Raw* displayed *MyHtmlData* with html tags (didn't render html, just displayed it). I guess, that is because the data was HTML encoded already, as Zdravko Danev mentioned:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.MyHtmlData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use literal control in asp.net to display the text and it will render it accordingly.

```
literal1.text = htmlcodeuwanttodisplay
```

Answer (score -3):

Did you try something like

```
Server.HtmlEncode("<p><span style='color: #ff0000;'>asdsada</span></p>");
```

Comment: Check your answer before you post it here please. this won't solve the problem. HtmlDecode is the answer.