# html decoded string displaying code in literal

Tags: asp.net

I have an html coded string that I want to pull from an xml document and display in a literal. My code looks like this:

XML

```
<test>&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Here is a &amp;lt;em&amp;gt;test&amp;lt;/em&amp;gt; to &amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;consider&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
</test>
```

Code behind

```
ccXML.Load(Server.MapPath("~/customContent.xml"));
var welcomeMessage = ccXML.SelectSingleNode("/test");
string message = welcomeMessage.InnerXml;
storyBox.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(message);
```

HTML

```
<asp:Literal ID="storyBox" Mode="PassThrough" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Currently, the literal is displaying the html tags to the user like this

```
"<p>Here is a <em>test</em> to <strong>consider</strong></p>."
```

What I want, instead, is for the tags to execute (i.e. format the text). Anyone see where I'm going wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help.

edit: Someone directed me to this earlier answer on another thread ([C# ASP.net render HTML String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644643/c-sharp-asp-net-render-html-string)
), however, the solution (casting my string as a string) does not fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I encode the target HTML I get this instead:

```
&lt;p&gt;Here is a &lt;em&gt;test&lt;/em&gt; to &lt;strong&gt;consider&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

That worked fine for me when I used it in the `<test>` element

Comment: That works for me too. I discovered that I was using an unnecessary Server.HtmlEncode() when adding the html string to my xml document. After removing that, the text that gets added to the xml document now looks like your example and all of the tags execute appropriately when added to the literal. Thanks!

Comment: That makes sense - if you decode the original string twice then it works