# TinyMCE WYSIWYG text formatting after saving Display Text With HTML tags on ASP.NET Core 1.0 web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, tinymce

I'm using tinyMCE 4.3.3 version & ASP.Net Core 1.0  - I successfully use the editor to encode text to html format and save it to a database. here is photo:
[tinymce-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mc64.jpg)

but problem is how displaying formatted text. look another photo
[tinymce-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCyy0.png)

after several day of searching I did not found any helpful material.
this is code ex. how i implement tinymce :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src='//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#PostShortText,#PostLongText',
    theme: 'modern',
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
      'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
      'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor'
    ],
    content_css: 'css\content.css',
    toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons'
  });
    </script>
```

***model code:***

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace techinfo.ge.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }
        public string PostShortText { get; set; }
        public string PostLongText { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Category> CategoryName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> TagName { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostAddTime { get; }
    }
}
```

**post creator view page**:

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Post</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="PostTitle" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="PostTitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PostTitle" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="PostShortText" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <textarea asp-for="PostShortText" id="PostShortText" class="form-control" ></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="PostShortText" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="PostLongText" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <textarea asp-for="PostLongText" id="PostLongText" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="PostLongText" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CategoryName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="CategoryName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CategoryName" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TagName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="TagName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TagName" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

***controller code*** :

```
    namespace techinfo.ge.Controllers
{
    public class PostsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public PostsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Posts
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Post.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Posts/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var post = await _context.Post.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PostID == id);
            if (post == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(post);
        }

        // GET: Posts/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Posts/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("PostID,PostTitle,PostShortText,PostLongText,CategoryName,TagName")] Post post)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(post);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(post);
        }

        // GET: Posts/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var post = await _context.Post.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PostID == id);
            if (post == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(post);
        }

        // POST: Posts/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("PostID,PostTitle,PostShortText,PostLongText")] Post post)
        {
            if (id != post.PostID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(post);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!PostExists(post.PostID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(post);
        }

        // GET: Posts/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var post = await _context.Post.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PostID == id);
            if (post == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(post);
        }

        // POST: Posts/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var post = await _context.Post.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PostID == id);
            _context.Post.Remove(post);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        private bool PostExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Post.Any(e => e.PostID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

***I know this has come up before but I've been looking and I'am still lost.***
Thanks

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it seems like the issue is not regarding the TinyMCE implementation. Most likely the issue is at the part where you display your result page. Your output being encode as a plain text. You should decode your HTML to show your expected result. You may reference to this [C# ASP.net render HTML String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644643/c-sharp-asp-net-render-html-string) on how to do this.

Comment: @Zesky this seems very helpful but i don't understand where to implement this peace of code `<%= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string)objRow["Post"]) %>` . in the view page?