# Display text stored in a database with markup correctly in HTML

Tags: html, css, sql, asp.net-core

I'm trying to allow notes to be stored in a database that, when retrieved, are displayed with styling. For example, the following text is stored in a notes column in the database:

```
<b><u>Scanning PC:</b></u>
// Tech Support //)
```

I have tried a `<span>`, I've also tried `<div>` with `contenteditable` and originally I had a `<textarea>` none of which have worked.

It is simply displayed like so:

[image]

The entire span in HTML:

```
<span style="resize: none; height: 500px;">
   <b><u>Scanning PC:</b></u>
    // Tech Support //)
</span>
```

Update:

The element in the Razor View:

```
<span style="resize: none; height: 500px;">@Model.Notes</span>
```

Comment: What are you using to get it out of the DB?

Comment: If PHP you need htmlspecialchars_decode()

Comment: @Dammeul Unfortunately not PHP, SQL and LinQ

Comment: What ASP.Net component are you using to display the value? You should disable its HTML escaping, if any...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Please see my edit.. it's simply a span with the notes on in a Razor view.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<%= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string)objRow["Post"]) %>
```

[C# ASP.net render HTML String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644643/c-sharp-asp-net-render-html-string)